# Swift: NSURL properly returning HTML from URL in Playground but crashes simulator when used in an app

Tags: php, xcode, swift, nsurl

I am using NSURL to get the HTML of a website which works great in the Playground, but crashes the simulator when I use it in an app.
Playground Code:

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

// Let asynchronous code run
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
  data, response, error in
  let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  if error != nil {
    print("Error: \(error)")
  }
  print("Response: \(response)")
  print("Response String: \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```

App Code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func testButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString)"
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Error upon crash:
2015-10-27 20:14:54.105 testProject[51314:431730] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

I have used the code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func testButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            print("hey \(data)")
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString)"
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

And in my console the following is printed:

```
2015-10-28 02:54:49.284 trial[58972:2551861] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
hey nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

As you can see `data` is nil. It might be related to the fact that http is blocked due to App Transport Security.

Comment: The label is connected properly. I am able to alter it's content by replacing the NSURL code with testLabel.text = "Text changed". Do you have any other ideas as to why this does not work? Thanks

Comment: @NickPitoniak in that case "data" must be nil. Check this with print()

Comment: print(data) returns a large pool of 8 character alpha numeric strings, so I do not think it is nil. If you have any other ideas to fix this problem please let me know. Thank you for the help

Comment: @NickPitoniak check my updated answer - I have ran your code and print() returns nil for data. Most likely App Transport Security blocks opening of http which is why it is nil

Comment: Thank you for the help. I attempted to add code to the info.plist file to bypass this problem, however I was not able to type any code as it is all options. Here is a screenshot of my info.plist: http://i.imgur.com/mZYOGLZ.png . As you can see, there is no place (that I see) to add this code: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
     </dict>

Comment: @NickPitoniak select last row in your Info.plist and hit Enter

Comment: Thank you for the help. I made the changes to the Info.plist (http://i.imgur.com/wwix43u.jpg), however  am still getting a crash. Here is my error report if you get a change to look at it: 2015-10-28 12:42:48.772 testProject[58771:519590] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)